# NHibernate collection size without loading the entire collection

Tags: sql, linq, nhibernate, hql

:)

I have the following classes:

- **Dislike**

  - DislikedComment *(Comment)*
  - MemberId *(int)*
- **Comment**

  - Dislikes *(List<Dislike>)*
  - Text *(String)*
  - ArticleId *(int)*

(Extra properties omitted for brevity)

These classes are mapped using Fluent NHibernate in the expected way (with inverse on the list on comment). Now what I would like is for NHibernate to load the size of the *Dislikes* collection on Comment when loading the comment, but without loading the entire collection. I would very much like to avoid formulas (yuk @ native sql), and I would prefer for NHibernate to only fire one query. Is this in any way possible?

I know about the Extra Lazy feature, but as far as I know, this fires an extra query, which is not optimal with a list of hundreds of comments.

Comment: just for clairification you are asking to get a count of the children (dislikes) without having to load the entire graph?

Comment: @Rippo, yes, I only need the Dislike count.

Comment: In that case lazy="extra" is the perfect match for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common misconseption that you need 1 query for best perfomance.

Each join requires the database to perform additional work, and the complexity and cost of the query grows rapidly with each additional join. While relational database are optimized for handling joins, it is often more efficient to perform several separate queries instead of a single query with several joins in it.

in your case i would do 2 queries.

```
var dislikeCount = _session.Query<Comment>().Count(x=>x.Dislike);
var comments = _session.Query<Comment>().ToList();
```

ps: dont forget to wrap it inside a transaction.

Comment: True. But as always, profile both before you decide which is faster. _Premature_ optimization is generally not worth the time.

Comment: Unless you add lazy='extra' on your mappings you will perform a `select *` rather than `select count(*)`